# split integer number in R

Tags: r

```
exdata <- read.xlsx("123.xlsx", sheetIndex = 1)

id <- exdata$id

id // Class is factor
```

I have read the column from excel that has numbers in the below format

```
384508338244525230_47603942

384508338244525560_47603114
```

i don't need the number after "_" i.e 47603942 i simply want to omit it for further action.

can you please help me to get the number before "_" from the excel coulmn

Let me also the know the possible approach towards the solution

Answer (score 2):

You can use `sub`:

```
id <- factor("384508338244525230_47603942")
(id_ <- as.numeric(sub("([0-9]+)_.*", "\\1", id)))
# [1] 3.845083e+17
format(id_, scientific = FALSE)
# [1] "384508338244525230"
```

Answer (score 2):

Or you can try `strsplit`

```
id <-c("384508338244525230_47603942", "384508338244525560_47603114 ", "384508338244525560_47603114 ")
id <- as.factor(id)
new_id <- sapply(id, function(str){split <- unlist(strsplit(as.character(str), "_")); return(split[1])})
print(new_id)
```